# Thoth.Json get result

Tags: f#

Should be nice simple one.

I parse some JSON with Thoth.Json.Net

```
let children = Decode.Auto.fromString<floorplan_table>(parentTable.mergedchildren)
```

Which returns a Result

```
Result<floorplan_table, string>
```

How do I actually access the floorplan_table and it's key/values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you access to the `floorplan_table` inside the `Result`:

```
match children with
    | Ok floorplan -> doSomethingWith floorplan
    | Error msg -> handleError msg
```